# How to change font color of text coming from NSLocalizedString using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslocalizedstring

I am retrieving text from Localizable.strings and assigning to `label`. I  can't able to change the label colour. How to do this?

I tried like this way:

```
self.sampleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"HELLO WORLD", nil);
```

.    i am trying to change label text colour

Comment: What's the code of your tries to change the color ?

Comment: i tried all the ways how a label colour can be changed using [uiclolor redcolor] method and rgb method everything, as the text is coming from localized.string its not updating.

Comment: You change the Label textColor, not the String color (which doesn't have a color by the way, it's just a list of characters). Or use NSAttributedString, a version of "NSString" that can handle color, and other rendering effects.

Comment: [self.sampleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:59/255.0 green:140/255.0 blue:210/255.0 alpha:1]]; and i also used NSAttributedString also but still i am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code doesn't work?

```
self.sampleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.sampleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change label text color, not string color.

```
self.sampleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do like this:

```
sampleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(188/255.f) green:... blue:... alpha:1.0];
```